# How can I provide a client application (port 443) the ability to consume a REST API (port 9000) on the same server when the port is not public facing?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, express

I am running an angular (1.5+) application on node with express and ui-router, and I would like to connect this application to a REST API that is running on the same server but on a port that is not public facing (9000).

How can I configure my angular application and express server to consume the REST API on port 9000 using server side logic?

An example route and parameter that I would like to hit my REST API on port 9000 would be https://example.com/item/123

Comment: You could setup a reverse proxy with your webserver (apache, nginx, etc) that proxies requests to /item/* to your rest api. but that would be effectively making the api public facing.

Comment: if I don't want the API public facing am I most likely to be running code in the middleware layer of express?

Comment: that or in a route, but yeah. sounds like a remote proxy might not be the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

Normally i use [Express Http Proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) to solve this problem. It is very configurable.

Example code would be:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

// app is your express based Web application in port 443
var app = require('express')();

app.use('/item', proxy('localhost:9000', {
    forwardPath: function(req, res) {
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
}));
```

Using this middleware you can provide custom handling of the request before and after the request to the private API has been performed. Read the documentation for more examples.